# css background gradient with opaque pattern on top

Tags: html, css

**[FIDDLE GOES HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v82Luxfc/)**

Below is an image of what I am trying to accomplish in CSS:

[image]

As you can see, I have a gradient with a pattern on top. The pattern itself looks like this:
[image]

This pattern in photoshop has a 50% opacity to give it the look I have in the first image.

So to the HTML & CSS i've figured that I will need two elements to accomplish this just like this:

```
<header class="header background-gradient" id="header">
    <div class="background-pattern">
       // contents
    </div>
</header>
```

Now, what I have attempted is the following:

```
.background-gradient {
  background: #4261cf;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #3023ae), color-stop(100%, #53a0fd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='$gradient-start', endColorstr='$gradient-end',GradientType=1 );
  color: white; }
```

Above is the gradient effect which looks perfect, now where i struggle is with the pattern, if I apply the pattern in css like this:

```
.background-pattern {
  background: url(../images/pattern.jpg) repeat;
  opacity: .5; }
```

The issue I now face is all the child elements take on the .5 opacity and I don't know how I can avoid this?

You can checkout my fiddle to see this working in action.

Comment: use position fixed, z-index -1 and place it as separate dom element without children :)

Comment: last thing i want to do is used position fixed as their will be a lot more content within and below the two elements :/

Comment: Just assigning them with a z-index of -1 works with position absolute lol, thanks

Comment: Np :-) mark as answer if it suits you

Comment: When using this solution, if you look here: http://jsfiddle.net/v82Luxfc/8/ you can see that links don't work! Can you help me find a cure for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem, unfortunately a position absolute is required to work with z-index. Your choice whether to use it or not.

```
<header class="header background-gradient" id="header">
    <div class="background-pattern">
    </div>
</header>
<h1>Main Title</h1>

h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top:-500px;
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

(the indented stuff is new css and i just pulled out the h1 from the header element)

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v82Luxfc/7/

(nice gradient btw, looks sick!)

Comment: However, i have provided my own answer as to make this more responsive I would have to rely on javascript but this definitely does work :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5sbn1fn6/2/

HTML:

```
<header class="header background-gradient" id="header">
    <h1><a href="#">Main Title</a></h1>
    <div class="background-pattern"></div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  height: 500px; 
  width: 100%; }
.background-gradient {
  position: relative;
  background: #4261cf;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #3023ae), color-stop(100%, #53a0fd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='$gradient-start', endColorstr='$gradient-end',GradientType=1 );
  color: white;
position: relative;}

header > * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.background-pattern {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://i1091.photobucket.com/albums/i392/matid1994/pattern.jpg) repeat;
  opacity: .5;
  height: 500px; 
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top:0 ;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  z-index: 3;
}
h1 a {
    color: white;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
 <header class="header background-gradient" id="header">
<div class="background-pattern"></div>

// contents

</header>
```

and now

```
 .background-pattern {
background: url(../images/pattern.jpg) repeat;
position : absolutel;
opacity: .5; }
```

Comment: I am sorry keep the position : absolute and it will work. Sorry for the error

Comment: Even if the position is absolute the content within the header tag has the opaque issue: http://jsfiddle.net/v82Luxfc/2/

Comment: You have got the image opacity at 0.5 and the text "Main Page" has opacity 1. I think that was exactly your question.

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE GOES HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v82Luxfc/6/)**

I have managed to figure it out mostly based on the comment provided by @Zentoaku

I have applied to the background-gradient css:

```
.background-gradient {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
 // also here the gradient
}

.background-pattern {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  // here the pattern image and opacity
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else doing the same sort of thing

**EDIT:** You should also ensure that you set `.background-pattern` to have a `height` of `100%` to ensure it fits within the parent elements sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's already a suitable answer, but I figure I'll throw in one more different one. Some newer browsers let you layer multiple background images (or gradients) on top of each other. The result would look something like this:

```
.background-gradient {
  background: #4261cf;
  background-image: url(../images/pattern.jpg), -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%) ;
  background-image: url(../images/pattern.jpg), -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #3023ae), color-stop(100%, #53a0fd));
  background-image: url(../images/pattern.jpg), linear-gradient(45deg, #3023ae 0%, #53a0fd 100%);
}
```

(Not tested)

Since it's a lot of CSS, I decided to try omitting bg-repeat (is repeat by default) and some of the browser prefixes. (I'm not sure where `-ms-linear-gradient` came from. The first MS browser to support gradients allows you to use the standardized syntax)

Of course, this approach has the disadvantage of not working on older browsers. I believe IE9 is the earliest to support multiple backgrounds, and IE10 is the earliest to support gradients.

Comment: Nice, but i need the opacity to be set on the pattern.jpg

Comment: Would you get the same effect by making the image 50%-transparent in Photoshop? Or, are you not allowed to modify it?

Comment: well there is a gradient behind the pattern essentially. This would be different depending on the browser size so no i cannot do that :/

Comment: @Matthew ...I don't follow. What does the browser's size have to do with the method of making the pattern image transparent?